# Stretching vector in a specific direction and calculating its lenght

Tags: vectors

I know this should be very easy but unfortunately I couldn't attend few of my classes and now I don't understand how to calculate.

This is the problem:

I am given two points: $A=(1,-1)$ and $B=(-4,5)$. I calculated $AB$'s length, it is  $\sqrt{61}$.

I should extend $\overrightarrow{AB}$ vector to a point that my let's say $AC$'s length is  $\sqrt{549}$
.
I am really sorry if this is kinda gibberish, English isn't my main language, I know general English but not terms and such.

Comment: What observations have you made about the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

$$\overrightarrow{AB} = B - A= (b_1-a_1, b_2-a_2) = (-5,6)$$

$$\overrightarrow{AC} = k\cdot\overrightarrow{AB}= k\cdot(-5,6)=(-5k, 6k)$$

$$\left|\overrightarrow{AC}\right| = \Big|(5k, 6k)\Big| = \sqrt{(-5k)^2 + (6k)^2} = k\cdot\sqrt{61}$$

Now, you want $\left|\overrightarrow{AC}\right| = \sqrt{549},\ $ i. e.

$$k\cdot\sqrt{61} = \sqrt{549}$$

You will obtain $k = 3,$ so $$\overrightarrow{AC} = 3\cdot\overrightarrow{AB} = 3\cdot(-5,6)=(-15, 18)$$

and

$$\color{red}C = A + \overrightarrow{AC} = (1,-1) + (-15,18) =\color{red}{(-14, 17)}$$